# What does the LogiLink ID0052 Bluetooth USB adapter look like?

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I have a LogiLink ID0052 Bluetooth slim keyboard which I don't need any more and I'd like to sell.I'm quite sure it came with a USB Bluetooth adapter, but I can't identify it.

Since I have several of those small devices (USB sticks, WLAN sticks, Bluetooth sticks), I'd really like to give the correct one away.

I tried

- to find images via Google Image search
- to identify the 2 items labelled LogiLink I have available, but they seem to be WL0084B WLAN adapters

**What is printed on a LogiLink ID0052 Bluetooth stick that would uniquely identify it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [the ID0052 online manual](http://logilink.org/media/datasheets/ID0052.pdf) more thoroughly, I find

> Package contents
>
> • 1 x Wireless Bluetooth Keyboard
>
> • 2 x AAA Alkaline
>
> • 1 x User Manual

So there is no USB Bluetooth adapter included and I must have bought a 3rd party Bluetooth adapter along with it.